# Transferir arquivos .class para a pasta /web-inf no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlet, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web para um trabalho final da faculdade.

Ao criar arquivos .jsp para a aplicação, dá erro pois ele não encontra a classe do servlet. As classes e os arquivos .class devem estar dentro de uma pasta oculta chamada classes. Tenho que criar essa pasta? Pois eu não achei.

Gostaria de saber se tenho que copiar toda a pasta src, que está em 'Java Resources' e/ou tenho que transferir a localização dos arquivos .class para a pasta /web-inf/classes.

Answer (score 1):

No eclipse se voce clicar com o botão direito sobre seu projeto e ir em properties > Java build Path, voce deve encontrar na aba source um campo chamado 'default output path', é aqui que o eclipse gera os arquivos .class quando o projeto é compilado.

neste caso bastaria setar este campo para web-inf/classes.

No entanto dependendo do caso, talvez não seja necessário mudar a pasta do eclipse, na maioria dos casos basta exportar para WAR(caso servidor externo), ou caso esteja utilizando um plugin, alguns plugins nem necessitam que configure o caminho para os arquivos .class, e em outros voce pode alternativamente configurar o caminho atual para os arquivos .class ao invés de mudar onde o .class é gerado.

Answer (score 0):

Estou assumindo que o seu servidor de aplicações é o Tomcat.

A pasta `src` só é importante para gerar os arquivos `.class`, mas os arquivos em `src` não são necessários para rodar a aplicação no servidor de aplicações, portanto você não precisa copiar essa pasta.

Já a pasta `WEB-INF/classes` é necessária, crie-a e jogue os arquivos lá, respeitando a estrutura de subpastas (isto é, se há subpastas na pasta `classes` do seu projeto do Eclipse, mantenha essas pastas em `WEB-INF/classes`). Em outras palavras, copie a pasta `classes` do projeto Eclipse inteira e cole dentro de WEB-INF. A propósito, a pasta é dita "oculta" porque o que tem dentro de WEB-INF não fica acessível pela sua aplicação web.

Um livro que explica direitinho todo o processo é o *"Use a Cabeça: Servlets & JSP"*. Quem sabe você acha ele por aí...